# Unable to connect kafka server in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, apache-kafka

I'm using package `rapide/laravel-queue-kafka`, but it's throwing below error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
>     Class 'Rapide\LaravelQueueKafka\LaravelQueueKafkaServiceProvider' not found

I've added the `LaravelQueueKafkaServiceProvider` to the providers array in `config/app.php`:

```
Rapide\LaravelQueueKafka\LaravelQueueKafkaServiceProvider::class,
```

Comment: Can you provide more details on your problem?

Comment: When I run the project it's showing above error?

Comment: Please provide code such that others can reproduce your problem. Additionally, that error message is thrown by PHP itself, so there is no connection to Kafka